# Can I connect a LoadBalancer(that has public IP) to API management?

Tags: azure, routes, load-balancing, azure-api-management, azure-load-balancer

I would like to route traffic with a Load Balancer to API mgm, can I choose the API management in any LB solutions?

Comment: You can assign your own public IP to an Stv2 APIM service but not LB. for your scenario, you can deploy the apim to internal vnet and expose it through application gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. load balancer cannot be used for API management.

> ***Azure Load Balancer***– It operates at layer 4 (Transport Layer) of the
> OSI Network Stack and supports TCP and UDP protocols. However, it
> targets Virtual Machines and Scale Sets only. ***It cannot be used for
> PaaS services like API Management.*** Furthermore, it targets load
> balancing of regional traffic and is deployed within a single region,
> which means a single point of failure..

For more in detail you can refer this [Document](https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/load-balancing-public-and-private-traffic-to-azure-api-management#:%7E:text=Azure%20Load%20Balancer%20%E2%80%93%20It%20operates%20at%20layer,be%20used%20for%20PaaS%20services%20like%20API%20Management.).

Comment: Thanks @VenkatesanSettu, so if i get this right, I cant use LB but rather Application Gateway? since I need to(can I?) choose API Management at Gateway backend pool settings.

Comment: can you refer this  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway) integrate api mangement for application gateway